# CiviCase losing Relationship in Case?

Tags: wordpress, civicase, upgrade, relationships

Since upgrading to 4.7.3 on WordPress, some of our Cases seem to be losing a relationship role.  They are not linked to the case from the contact record either, even after re-adding them to the case.  This is a custom relationship role.  Additionally, these contacts are not displaying a number of activities.  I'm assuming these activities are related to the cases, but since I can't see them, I'm just assuming at this point.  I don't see any activity in the CiviCRM logs.  Has anyone else seen anything similar?

EDIT:
On further digging, playing, breaking, reviewing, and linking, I believe that I have found a bug.  However, I'd love to see some confirmation.  I have a case, associated with a custom created relationship in a Case Role.  This is not the client, but a special type of case manager.  When looking at the case, everything appears as one would expect.  Clicking on this special case manager contact record takes me to the correct record.  However, there is no case listed in the Cases tab.  In the Relationships tab, the relationship to the case is there, along with the More -> Manage Case # link.  When I click on that, things do not show correctly.  There is shows the case name as the contact record and does not show the correct Role relationships.

Additionally, it is a very different URL structure. The case URL from the Case Dashboard looks like:

https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fview%2Fcase&reset=1&id=32&cid=9462&action=view&context=dashboard&selectedChild=case

While the URL from the contact record Relationships tab looks like:

https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fview%2Fcase&action=view&reset=1&cid=95409&id=32